# How to get count based on multiple groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find the most simple way of getting these counts.

Table structure

GroupId, EventId, UserId, TypeId
100, 1, 1, 1
100, 2, 1, 1
100, 1, 1, 0
100, 1, 3, 0
101, 1, 1, 1

Group has a 1 to many with Event.
1-n Events can be linked to a Group

1) Count of groups where User 1 is the only user for typeid 1 (Can be multiple events per group, all must be type 1)

2) Count of groups where User 1 is the only user for typeid 0 (Can be multiple events per group, all must be type 0)

3) Count of groups where User 1 is NOT the only user for typeid 1 (Can be multiple events per group,  all must be type 1)

4) Count of groups where User 1 is NOT the only user for typeid 0 (Can be multiple events per group,  all must be type 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use count(case when) to solve this problem.

```
select count(case when t2.cn=1 and t1.UserId = 1 and t1.TypeId =1 then 1 else null end) as case1,
       count(case when t2.cn=1 and t1.UserId = 1 and t1.TypeId =0 then 1 else null end) as case2,
       count(case when t2.cn>1 and t1.UserId = 1 and t1.TypeId =1 then 1 else null end) as case3,
       count(case when t2.cn>1 and t1.UserId = 1 and t1.TypeId =1 then 1 else null end) as case4
 from table1 t1
 join (select count(distinct UserId) as cn, TypeId, from table) t2
 on  t1.TypeId = t2.TypeId
```

in count(case when) you then 1 means it will count, null will not be count. so you just need to figure out what case it should count is ok.

Comment: I think this is what I need but how would I do the count per groupid?

Comment: @user3953989 so you mean there are same groupid, same userid, same  typeid but different eventid in the table? now in this case, since the eventId is irrelevant you can cut the duplicated data before you do the query. so in my script above, you need change the t1 table, like (select distinct groupid,userid ... from table) t1

Comment: Thanks I will try that now but yes a group may have 30+ events with different users associated to each event. I need to know how many groups have only user 1 events and how many groups have events with different users. I.e. Group 10, has 20 events, all 20 events are tied to User 1. I need to count that group in the first case. If any of the events have a different user, that would count in the 3rd case. (for type=1)

Comment: @user3953989 it's quite different from the case you asked but the solution is same. if you got any problem, you can check the count(case when) to see something more